# WPF Window has Owner handle but no Owner

Tags: wpf, window

I created a normal WPF window that has no `Window.Owner`.
This window has an owner handle set when checking its `WindowInteropHelper.Owner` property. I also recognized that the owned window rectangle is cascaded somewhere on the desktop with each new window (using GetWindowRect).

Can anyone tell me what's going on there ?
Is it something like a default behavior in wpf for setting the startup position to the owner's center if there is no real owner?

The thing is, I would like to distinguish two cases in order to be able to center the window to the real(!) owner window center or - if there is no owner - the screen center:

- The window owner is a non-wpf window (e.g. if used in an vsto plugin)
- There is in deed no owner window

If anyone has an idea how I could distinguish that or achive my requirements, I'd be happy :)

Best regards
Lumo

Answer (score 0):

The `Window.Owner` property only works in case the parent window is a WPF window. Since the entire parent-children structure of windows is handled by the operating system, it is very well possible to establish such a relation between windows of different frameworks.

So in case you are able to retrieve a window handle using the `WindowInteropHelper` you know that there is a owner window. But it could be a native window or a windows forms window.

Since all you want is the bounding box of the owner window, you can easily use the Windows API to fetch the bounding box. The function you want to use for that is: [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx)

I assume you are using a managed language like C# or VB.net so there is the example how to access the function with C#:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT {
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

The handle you need for the function is the window handle you fetch with the `WindowInteropHelper`.

In case your handle does not point to a window, the function will return `false`. In that case your handle is either invalid or was null. In such cases you have to fall back to the screen size to center your window.

**EDIT 1:** Since I totally misunderstood the actual problem, here is another idea. There is a helper "window" handle that always covers the entire screen. If I understand that concept correctly a window that is shown on the desktop is always attached to this desktop window. You can fetch the handle using the [`GetDesktopWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633504.aspx) function.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
```

Comment: I think you didn't get the point. I already used GetWindowRect and it returns true, although I didn't set any parent to the window.
The rect is cascaded, as I wrote in my question.
Thanks anyway for your answer !

Comment: Ah now I get it. Is it possible that you get the handle of the "DesktopWindow"? There is a support window handle that always covers the entire screen. You can fetch the handle to it with the `GetDesktopWindow` function. Maybe that helps finding out what is the real parent of the window?

Comment: I checked the DesktopWindow Pointer, its a different one.
With each new window, there is another owner handle and this new owner window is cascaded.
Isn't this the default behavior of a window in WPF ?